# Invalid Accept-Ranges header value for HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, partial

I have a simple code to get Accept-Ranges header value for URLs. Lastly I tried a link to test the code and it returned wrong value.

> **Method 1:** This code returns *false* as RangeAllowed.

```
string url = "https://cdn.gomlab.com/gretech/player/new/GOMPLAYERGLOBALSETUP.EXE";

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Accept = "*/*";
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.Timeout = 5000;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

bool rangeAllowed = resp.GetResponseHeader("Accept-Ranges") == "bytes";
Console.WriteLine(rangeAllowed);

req.Abort();
resp.Close();
```

> **Method 2:** `WebRequest.AddRange` returns the correct PartialContent, `true`.

```
string url = "https://cdn.gomlab.com/gretech/player/new/GOMPLAYERGLOBALSETUP.EXE";

HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
req.Accept = "*/*";
req.KeepAlive = false;
req.Timeout = 5000;
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
req.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;

req.AddRange(0, 99);
HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;

bool rangeAllowed = (resp.ContentLength == 100);
Console.WriteLine(rangeAllowed);

req.Abort();
resp.Close();
```

Is it just wrong for me? If not, what is the reason of this problem?

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're asking. Have you looked at the value that *is* returned from `resp.GetResponseHeader("Accept-Ranges")`?

Comment: Yes, I looked. It returns an empty string.

Comment: Okay. So it's not generating that header. That's entirely valid - see https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5 "Origin servers that accept byte-range requests MAY send `Accept-Ranges: bytes` but are not required to do so."

Comment: So, the 100% guarantee method is to send a partial content request and get the response?

Comment: Well yes, "Try to do something and see whether it works" is always a way of seeing whether you can do it...